# Issue communicating with ESP32 (WT32-S1) with my USB FTDI (hw-417-v1.2)

Tags: arduino-uno, esp32, softwareserial

Basically im trying to communicate bewtween my ESP32 (WT32-S1) and my USB FTDI (hw-417-v1.2) when I run it in the Arduino IDE I get the error "***Failed to connect to ESP32: Serial data stream stopped: Possible serial noise or corruption.***" Not too sure why this happens, I've plugged in the WT32 to the FTDI as follows:

WT32 RXD - FTDI TXD

WT32 TXD - FTDI RXD

WT32 GND -  FTDI GND

WT32 5V - FTDI 5V

The FTDI is directly plugged into my PC and I've installed the necessary drivers as far as I know. Fair to mention its communicating serially with my arduino uni using SoftwareSerial. Here is the code ESP32 side:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#define MYPORT_TX 15
#define MYPORT_RX 14

SoftwareSerial myPort(MYPORT_RX, MYPORT_TX);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  myPort.begin(115200);
}

void loop(){
  Serial.println(myPort.read()); // read from software serial interface, write to hardware serial
  myPort.println(Serial.read()); // read from hardware serial interface, write to software serial
}
```

Code Arduino uno side:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial serial2(5, 6); // choose pins that are not being used by anything else

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  serial2.begin(115200);
}

void loop(){
  Serial.println(serial2.read()); // read from software serial interface, write to hardware serial
  serial2.println(Serial.read()); // read from hardware serial interface, write to software serial
}
```

The connection from WT32 to Arduino Uno is as follows:

WT32 GND - Uno GND

WT32 IO15 - Uno 5

WT32 IO14 - Uno 6

Main issue as said is the "***Failed to connect to ESP32: Serial data stream stopped: Possible serial noise or corruption.***", mentioning the rest to give you a full picture.

Cheers!

Comment: How did you load that program onto the ESP32 ? Using the same FTDI adaptor ?
The ESP32 is a 3.3 volt device. How are you powering it and what level shifting (if any) are you using between it and the Uno? Are grounds connected between the Uno and the ESP ?

Comment: Welcome! I don't suppose you have a 2nd ESP32 that you can try? I sometimes find that if one doesn't work, then another might.

Comment: Also, is your IDE set to communicate on `115200` baud? If not, you need to make sure the code matches. Edit: Hmm, though you mention SoftwareSerial works, which is interesting.

Comment: 6v6gt yes, my ESP32 supports 5.5 volts and you can use both, same with the FTDI, I tried both same result,

Nickbolton i only have one sadly and both are set to 115200 baud, i think this is a hardware issue, buying a new FTDI and new cables

Comment: Good luck! Hope that works. Waiting for parts is always the least fun bit.

Comment: @PrinceSalmon Can you add a link to your particular ESP32 (WT32-S1) module. This data sheet implies a max voltage of 3.6 volts: http://www.wireless-tag.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/WT32-S1-DataSheet-V1.5.pdf

Answer (score -1):

Ive solved my problem, to any other people who have this problem, make sure you use a CP2102 instead, and plug according to this:

```
CP2101    WT32
TXD ----- RX0
RXD ----- TX0
GND ----- GND
5V  ----- 5V
```

Then plug the WT32 IO0 pin to GND to enter download mode, I'm personally using an external 5v PS as the WT32 needs quite a lot of power.